# wpf CroppedBitmap crop image as pixel values in double

Tags: image, crop

I am Cropping the image using CroppedBitmap method in WPF. 
Required input parameter is int32Rect. 
But, my image Height and Width values are in double (pixel).
So without truncate the Double to Int, i want to crop the image by using double values (pixel)

Comment: Pixels are integer units. What meaning is there to fractional pixels?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **PixelWidth** and **PixelHeight** properties, if you can't see them (*Intellisense* can't find them) you can use the **as** operator to cast it to a **BitmapSource**. For example:

```
BitmapSource src = yourImage as BitmapSource;
CroppedBitmap chunk = new CroppedBitmap(src, new Int32Rect(src.PixelWidth / 4, src.PixelHeight / 4, src.PixelWidth / 2, src.PixelHeight / 2));
```

By the way, the **as** operator returns **null** if conversion couldn't be performed (so you may want to check if `src` is not `null` after the conversion in the example above, unless you're sure that `yourImage` is derived from *BitmapSource*).

---

**EDIT :**

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but here is a method that accepts a **Rect** (floating-point values) as input and returns a *CroppedBitmap*:

```
    public static CroppedBitmap GetCroppedBitmap(BitmapSource src, Rect r)
    {
        double factorX, factorY;

        factorX = src.PixelWidth / src.Width;
        factorY = src.PixelHeight / src.Height;
        return new CroppedBitmap(src, new Int32Rect((int)Math.Round(r.X * factorX), (int)Math.Round(r.Y * factorY), (int)Math.Round(r.Width * factorX), (int)Math.Round(r.Height * factorY)));
    }
```

Example:

```
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"c:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    CroppedBitmap chunk = GetCroppedBitmap(bmp, new Rect(bmp.Width / 4, bmp.Height / 4, bmp.Width / 2, bmp.Height / 2));
    JpegBitmapEncoder jpg = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    jpg.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(chunk));
    FileStream fp = new FileStream("chunk.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    jpg.Save(fp);
    fp.Close();
```

Comment: Still you are converting the values to Int32Rect. But i want to supply the double DataType values. Ex: X = 450.56, Y = 331.35, Width = 35.46, Height = 91.69. I want to Crop the image by using those values.

Comment: You are using Rect to crop the image. Rect will support width as Int data type. But i need to pass Width value as double data type. Ex: 35.46 pixels.

Comment: @Lakshmanan so you didn't even test the code...[Rect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) stores **double** values, and the properties `Width` and `Height` of **BitmapSource** (_BitmapImage_ derives from _BitmapSource_) are **double** values as well. I tested the code with some images, and it seems to work... ;)

Comment: I tried. But my scenario is different. I have one bitmapsource. BitmapSource Width is 1024, PixelWidth is 1024. Now, image to be cropped at 47.3 width. In your example, you round the value from Double(47.3) to Int(47)