# Cropping the image with double values

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap

I'm Cropping the image using `CroppedBitmap` method in WPF. Required input parameter is int32Rect. But, my image Height and Width values are in double (pixel). So without truncate the Double to Int, I want to crop the image by using double values (pixel).
Due to truncation, it causes loss of image quality and slight white space on borders of the cropped image.
Is this possible?

Here's my code.

```
public static BitmapSource SaveSelectedRegion(BitmapSource source, Shape rubberBand)
{
    try
    {
        int rubberX = Convert.ToInt32(rubberBand.Margin.Left);
        int rubberY = Convert.ToInt32(rubberBand.Margin.Top);
        int rubberW = Convert.ToInt32(rubberBand.Width);
        int rubberH = Convert.ToInt32(rubberBand.Height);

        // it seems cropped bitmap only support int parameters.
        CroppedBitmap crop = new CroppedBitmap(source
          , new Int32Rect(rubberX, rubberY, rubberW, rubberH));

        var res= crop as BitmapSource;
        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've already looked into this article too.
[wpf CroppedBitmap crop image as pixel values in double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214827/wpf-croppedbitmap-crop-image-as-pixel-values-in-double) and It didn't work to me.

Comment: Try `int rubberX = (int)Math.Floor(rubberBand.Margin.Left)` and `int rubberW = (int)Math.Ceiling(rubberBand.Width)`

Comment: @Clemens good idea. but it doesn't work. probably I should try another class like `System.Drawing.Graphics`

Comment: It doesn't work isn't a very precise problem description. However, be aware that cropping a bitmap at non-integer pixel values doesn't make much sense. You'll have to round your rectangle values somehow.

Comment: "But, my image Height and Width values are in double (pixel)." That sentence makes no sense. How can you have 5.3 pixel? Measurements in pixel must be a Integer. Pixel is really just another word for "Array Element that stores color values". Any other measurements of the Image are generated from pixels and DPI value. Otherwise it is nota digital imiage yet.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree. But zooming ratio in this canvas makes rubberBand double values. so I tried to make rubberband to have rounded int values before this function, but same happened. without zoom, it works so fine.